# unable to locate sourcecode of scipy

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, scipy

This is I know is a duplicate question and is trivial. Could somebody help me to find the source code of `scipy.maxentropy.bigmodel.stochapprox` ([link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.maxentropy.arrayexp.html?highlight=maxentropy)).

I looked [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy).

I did try following:

```
import inspect
import scipy 
inspect.getsourcelines(scipy)
```

or

```
??scipy (in notebook)
```

**these above does not give desired result.**

also following generates error

```
import.maxentropy.bigmodel.stochapprox
(ImportError: No module named maxentropy.bigmodel.stochapprox)
```

I need to see how stochapprox is computed in scipy.

**Never mind found it, (pretty old thought):**

https://github.com/qsnake/scipy/blob/master/src/scipy/maxentropy/maxentropy.py

Comment: FYI: `maxentropy` was removed from version [0.11.0 of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.11.0.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser do you have other recommended library for that?

Comment: The release notes for 0.11.0 suggest "Logistic regression in scikits.learn is a good and modern alternative for this functionality."

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to implement this in MCMC of networks. I will also check that out.